# ADALjs and Azure AD auth for Wep API project

Tags: azure, authorization, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a client app and Web API app hosted on different domains and want to utilize ADAL.js in my client app to login in my Web API app, but still getting Unauthorized error.

In web api web.config I've specified my AAD details:

```
<add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="http://clientappurl/" />
<add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.windows.net/...3596365/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" />
<add key="ida:ClientId" value=".....388ffcc3" />
<add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="....gBsD7o=" />
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="........onmicrosoft.com" />
<add key="ida:TenantId" value="........96365" />
<add key="ida:Auth" value="https://login.windows.net/" />
<add key="ida:GraphUrl" value="https://graph.windows.net" />
```

And updated Startup.Auth.cs with following:

```
 app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Audience = "http://myclientapp",
            Tenant = "developertenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            AuthenticationType = "OAuth2Bearer",                               
        });
```

On the client I've specified endpoints (my api url), tenant and clientId. ADALjs redirects user to microsoft login page and looks like after sucessfull login it writes some data to local storage. But API app still respondes with Unauthorized error.

Are there any tutorials on how properly configure wep api and client apps hosted on different domains to utilize AAD?

How can I read authorized user details like AAD user group from my Web API app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which shows how to read AAD group claims from a web app:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims

Once you have the tokens, you can then call a Web API, which is shown by this example: 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect

There's a good list of AAD examples here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/